# Pandas DataFrame : groupby then transpose

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1-sensor':['608', '608', '2158', '2158'],
          '2-day':['2017-12-11', '2017-12-12', '2017-12-11', '2017-12-12'],
          '3-voltage':[30, 31, 28, 29]})
```

df :

```
  1-sensor       2-day  3-voltage
0      608  2017-12-11         30
1      608  2017-12-12         31
2     2158  2017-12-11         28
3     2158  2017-12-12         29
```

And I would like to make it look like this :

```
pd.DataFrame({'1-sensor':['608', '2158'],
              '2017-12-11':[30, 28],
              '2017-12-12':[31, 29]})
```

df :

```
  1-sensor  2017-12-11  2017-12-12
0      608          30          31
1     2158          28          29
```

I have tried different solutions combining `.groupby('sensor')` and `.unstack()` but not successful. Any good suggestions ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the desired input/output as code snippets, rather than images.

Comment: Are there any aggregations you want to perform? If not, there's no need for a groupby.

Comment: @Nae Sorry, I have removed the images.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No aggregations are needed, just this tricky transformation ! thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `pivot`, if there are no aggregations. This is actually more efficient -

```
df.pivot(index='1-sensor', columns='2-day', values='3-voltage')

2-day     2017-12-11  2017-12-12
1-sensor                        
2158              28          29
608               30          31
```

If there are any aggregations to be performed, use `pivot_table` and include `aggfunc=...`.

**Option 2**
Another solution with `set_index` + `unstack` -

```
df.set_index(['1-sensor', '2-day']).unstack()

          3-voltage           
2-day    2017-12-11 2017-12-12
1-sensor                      
2158             28         29
608              30         31
```

---

If aggregations are required, then `groupby` + `unstack` *will* do it. You were *this* close.

```
df.groupby(['1-sensor', '2-day'], sort=False).sum().unstack()  

          3-voltage           
2-day    2017-12-11 2017-12-12
1-sensor                      
608              30         31
2158             28         29
```

Replace `sum` with the aggfunction you want to use, *if* you need to use one.

Comment: Thank you for the rich answer. The first option works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with `pd.pivot_table`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['1-sensor'], columns = ['2-day'], values = '3-voltage').reset_index()
```